# Regex to scan a password with only alphabets and numbers and not any special character enclosed within double quotes or space

Tags: regex, passwords

I am using trufflehog for secret scanning.I need a regex that will scan for the password in a directory.

Regex must cover sample secrets mentioned below:

1. docker login -u "username" -p **"AKCp5budTFpbypBqQbGJPz3pGCi28pPiJhWczqjfYb9drAmd9LbRZbj6UpKFxJXA8ksWGc9fM"** docker.net
2. **BcClOi9FKdx77snJ36VC**
3. helm registry login -u "username" -p **"j2o7zfkZ1d074Hgfklj7cwR3ghDj3sI4"** registry.net

I tried with the below regex and it is detecting the third password mentioned from above 3, but without a space after the password.(Does not detect if I give the entire line as mentioned in option 3, but works if I remove **space** and **registry.net**)

`\\b(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[a-z]{2,})(?=.*[A-Z]{2,})(?=\\S+$)[^-@#:$%^&+=/,<>()._]{30,33}\\b`

1. Passwords are alphanumeric(**must** contain lower case, upper case and numbers)
2. Does not have any special characters in between
3. Are surrounded by either double quotes or space

Please help me frame 3 different regex to scan these passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
\b"?(?=[^'"@#^:$%&+=\/,<>()._\s-]*?[a-z])(?=[^'"@#^:$%&+=\/,<>()._\s-]*?[A-Z])(?=[^'"@#^:$%&+=\/,<>()._\s-]*?\d)[^'"@#^:$%&+=\/,<>()._\s-]{20,}"?\b
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/D4r869/1)